# HTML Video does not display correctly in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, mp4

I have a video tag as follows

```
<video  controls="controls"  >                            
 <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" > 
 <source src="video1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 <source src="video1.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

I'm using following doc type

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Video is displaying and playing correctly in Firefox and Chrome. But not in Internet Explorer. (checked in IE 9,10 and 11)

In IE it says "Invalid Source"

I have also added .htaccess file to the root with following contents.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I tried given solution in the post.. but no luck.

Comment: Same problem with IE 11 here. Works on the Internet, fails on localhost (running from VS 2012). Tried full paths as well as that META tag thingy - no joy. It's probably a setting in VS, but what that setting is is anyone's guess. Best to detect IE and serve up Flash instead of HTML5. MS is 5 years behind everyone else in HTML5 support.